# Calling DialogFragment in Activity

Tags: android

How can I call `DialogFragment` in my `Activity` the same way I'm calling it in my `FragmentActivity`?

Here  is my sample codes at my `FragmentActivity`:

```
private void showAlertDialog(int title, int message){

    AlertDialogFragment alert = AlertDialogFragment.createInstance(
            getActivity().getString(title),
            getActivity().getString(message));

    alert.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "Alert");

}
```

`alert.show( ???, "Alert" );`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if Activity extends FragmentActivity use `getSupportFragmentManager()`
if not use: `getFragmentManager()`

Comment: I already tried that one but I received an error at runtime because I'm trying to extend Activity instead of FragmentActivity I guessed. Any idea about that @user974801 ?

Comment: `getSupportFragmentManager()` if you are using `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: getFragmentManager() requires min API Level 11